# convert date from string format and sort

Tags: javascript, date-formatting

I am getting dates in string format from backend and I want to sort the dates in ascending order

I want to sort the data using date

```js
array.sort(function(a, b) {
  return new Date(parseInt(a.ResultTimestamp)).getTime() - new Date(parseInt(a.ResultTimestamp)).getTime();
});
```

date format that I am getting from backend

```
"ResultTimestamp": "2019-01-06-00.55.39.109000"
```

Comment: Seems like the format is invalid. `new Date("2019-01-06-00.55.39.109000")` returns `Invalid Date`

Comment: @MoshFeu how to convert it to a valid format?

Comment: The proper form you want to get it to is `2019-01-06 00:55:39.109000`

Comment: The second a.ResultTimestamp in the second line is b.ResultTimestamp, right?

Comment: @TakashiHarano yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As much as I know (and maybe not enough) you need a custom parsing function by extracting all the date segments and creating a new instance of `Date`.

```js
function parseDate(date) {
  const [year, month, day, time] = date.split('-');
  const [hours, minutes, seconds, fr] = time.split('.');
  return new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds).getTime();
}

const array = ['2018-01-06-00.55.39.109000', '2019-01-06-00.55.39.109000'];

array.sort(function(a, b) {
  return parseDate(b) - parseDate(a);
});

console.log(array);
```

I simplify the example, let me know if something is not clear.

Comment: @sm770 i think you called it in wrong way. You just need to pass your date string to `parseDate` function. Like this 

    array.sort(function(a, b) {
       return parseDate(b.ResultTimestamp) - parseDate(a.ResultTimestamp);
    });

Comment: @sm770 you see that it's working in my demo so I'll need to see your updated code to understand what's the problem. My guess, you define the `parseDate` in a [closure function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) (maybe in `$(document).ready` if you're using jQuery) or in `(function() {})()` some how so the function is not available in the context that you're trying to call it. For example: https://jsbin.com/zazoxup/edit?js,console